# reverse of a queue in c++

Tags: c++, stack, queue

this is a question from a exam paper i got stuck in below i have attached the question although i wasnt able to complete i have done some of it.

question:

Using the following class definitions of stack and queue classes write a templated function reverseQueue(?), that takes a pointer to queue as a parameter and uses stack object (or pointer to a stack object) to reverse the given queue. The function call to reverseQueue should reverse the data of the queue passed as a parameter. [Hint: Just call appropriate methods given below in your reverseQueue(?) function. You do not have to write implementation code for stack and queue classes/methods given below. Just read what each method does and use them according to your need.]

```
template <class T>
struct NODE {
    NODE<T> *pNext;
    T Data;
};

template <class T>
class stack{
    private:
       NODE<T> * top;

    public:
       stack();
       ~stack();
       void push (T data); //pushes a new node with data type //T in a stack
       bool pop (T &data); //pops out the top most node from //the stack
       void printStack(); //prints all elements of a stack
};

template <class T>
class queue {
    private:
        NODE<T> * front;
        NODE<T> * tail;
    public:
        queue ();
        ~queue();
        bool dequeue ( T & data); //removes first node from //a queue
        bool enqueue (T val); //appends a new node in a //queue
};
```

my answer is incomplete as i could not proceed further below is my answer whatever i have done

```
template <class T>
void reverseQueue(queue <T> *ptr){
    stack <T> *stackptr= new stack<T>;
    T temp;
    while(ptr->front !=NULL){

        temp=ptr->Data;
        ptr->dequee(ptr->Data);
        stackptr->push(temp);

     }

    // incomplete code
}
```

if anyone can give the answer that would be great

Comment: It looks like `stack` is basically the same as `queue` except the order is reversed. So you have started well; moving items from the queue (e.g. `1, 2, 3`) to the stack will reverse their order (e.g. `3, 2, 1`). Now you need to pop them off the stack and add them back to the queue.

Comment: @JonathanPotter but that is exactly where i cant think of the code i can write i know the concept but not the code to do it

Comment: Don't look at the private parts. You don't need a single pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo whatever i have done at the moment is it correct?

Comment: Basically you want `while (stack.pop) queue.enqueue()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose the input queue looks like

```
 1    2    3    4
 ^              ^
front           back
```

If we dequeue the items from it, we will get 1, 2, 3, 4.

Suppose now that we push these items onto a stack as we dequeue them.
It would look like this:

```
4  <- top
3
2
1  <- bottom
```

If we pop these, we will get 4, 3, 2, 1.

Now, if we enqueue these in a queue as we pop them from the stack, we will get

```
 4    3    2    1
 ^              ^
front           back
```

which is the reverse of the original queue.

Something like this should do it:

```
template <class T>
void reverseQueue(queue <T> *q){
    stack <T> s;
    T temp;
    // First build a stack (LIFO queue) from the (FIFO) queue.
    while (q->dequeue(temp))
    {
        s.push(temp);
    }
    // The first item in the queue is now at the bottom of the stack.
    // The last item is at the top.
    // The queue is empty.

    // If we enqueue them again they will be reversed.
    while (s.pop(temp))
    {
        q->enqueue(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
void reverseQueue(queue<T> *q_ptr)
{
  stack<T> *stack_ptr = new stack<T>();
  T temp;
  while(true)
  {
    if (q_ptr.dequeue(temp))
    {
      stack_ptr->push(temp);
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  while(true)
  {
    if (stack_ptr->pop(temp))
    {
      q_ptr.push(temp);
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  delete stack_ptr;
}
```

- Runtime Complexity : O(n) + O(n) = O(2*n) ~ O(n)
- Space Complexity : O(n) for the stack_ptr

Comment: Space complexity is actually constant.

Comment: Yes it can be constant if we implement it differently, but in my solution it is still O(n) as I am putting all in the stack in the 1st while loop.

Comment: @glaze You're removing each item from the queue, so the space used is constant.

Comment: Writing while(true){if(c){s;}else{break;})  instead of while(c)s; isn't good style. It borders on obfuscation.